# C++11, Mac, and Qt 5 installation?

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, c++11, qmake

I've posted this problem in Qt community [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/38948/) but with no hope. I’m using qmake to build my project. I’m using 
Mac 10.7.5
Xcode Version 4.3.3
Qt 5

First Method: (in project file .pro)

```
QT   += core
QT   -= gui

# --------- Project Settings ------------- #
TEMPLATE      = app
TARGET        = test
CONFIG       -= app_bundle
CONFIG       += console
CONFIG       += c++11    # <----- it doesn't work
SOURCES      += main.cpp
```

But after a lot of attempts and some suggestions from ppl in Qt community, I have ended up with the following settings

```
QT   += core 
QT   -= gui


# --------- Project Settings ------------- #
TEMPLATE      = app
TARGET        = test
CONFIG       -= app_bundle
CONFIG       += console


QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.7
```

But still no hope. These the errors that I'm getting

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-stdlib=libc++"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
```

g++ compiler doesn't recognize the commands. I've tested a c++11 code in Xcode and it worked with no problems. My settings for Xcode as following

In Xcode, I have to do the following settings

```
Build Options:
Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C ———————> Apple LLVM compiler 3.1
Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 – Language:
C++ Language ——————-> C++11[-std=c++11]
C++ Standard Library ———————> libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)
```

I don't know how can I set my .pro so that my program will recognize the header files of c++11

Comment: The gcc that was shipped in XCode is antique (4.2.1 I think) and probably has no C++11 support at all. I'd use clang.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, how can I specify the compiler in qmake? Another question, based on what you said, Xcode uses clang?

Comment: i use Qt5 on OSX with C++11 using QtCreator (i like that tool) and you can easily change your toolchain and set another compiler (specified in the QtCreator build settings, duno how to set in qmake pro files)

Comment: Use the mkspec "macx-clang”, pass it via "-spec macx-clang" or the QMAKESPEC environment variable.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, would you please show me a sample?

Comment: Call “qmake -spec macx-clang” or do “export QMAKESPEC=macx-clang && qmake"

Comment: Adding to Frank's correct suggestion: you need to rebuild Qt using clang. You're up for subtle problems if you mix gcc-built Qt with clang-built application that uses Qt.

Comment: I gave up. I tried everything but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The gcc compiler that comes packaged with XCode 4.3 doesnot support C++11, you have to use **Clang** compiler which supports it.
In Qt you can use the **makespec "macx-clang**" for C++11 support.